# Inheritance: Selecting which base class methods to inherit

Tags: c++, derived-class

I have a class `Base` and want to write a class `Derive` which inherits only some of the member functions from `Base`. Is there any convenient way to do this?

For example,

```
class Base
{
   ...
   void fooA();
   void fooB();
   ...
}
```

I wish to define a `class Derive` which inherits all members except `fooB` from `Base`.

Comment: What do you mean by "derives"?

Comment: If you only have `fooB` in `Derived`, all its other members will be derived from `Base`. Do you mean "override"?

Comment: The word "derive" is usually used when you talk about class relationships ("class A derives from class B so B is a base class). When we talk about functions, we use words "override" and "inherited": Class A overrides fooA but inherits fooB (IOW, fooA has a different implementation in class A but fooB stays the same). Could you rephrase your question with this in mind?

Comment: @molbdnilo The right opposite.

Comment: Your question makes no sense in its current form. You should clarify it.

Comment: @juanchopanza:  Made sense to me.  He wants `Derived` to derive from `Base`, but to pick and choose which methods from `Base` are inherited in `Derived`.

Comment: @molbdnilo,@Medinoc, yes, derives means overrides. Actually this problem results from the fact that, I wanted to override parts of the functions in class `Base` but also found `fooA` was dangerous if it can be called from `Derived`. I want `fooA` invisible in class `Derived` while avoiding affecting `Base`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you derive a subclass from a base class, you inherit *all* member functions from the base class (except the constructors & destructor, which are never inherited).  You cannot pick and choose which members to derive.

However, this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Depending on what you're *really* trying to do, you might be able to accomplish your actual goals.

You could change the visibility of a derived method:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
private: 
  using Base::fooB; // fooB() is now private
};
```

You could use private inheritance, and then make public only those methods you wish to provide:

```
class Derived : private Base
{
public:
  using Base::fooA;  // Only fooA() is public here
};
```

You could avoid inheritance altogether and [encapsulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) `Base` instead, and provide [bridge methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) for the resources in `Base` you wish to provide access for:

```
class Derived 
{
Base mBase; // private
public:
  void fooA() { mBase.fooA(); }
};
```

However, note that in the later two cases you lose some of the benfits of polymorphism.  In order to have a `Base*` point to something that is actually a `Derived`, you must use public inheritance.

Comment: Note that in the last two cases, a `Base *` cannot point to a `Derived` object. This is only possible for public inheritance, which establishes an *is-a* relationship

Comment: If I remember C++ inheritance right you also loose polymorphism with the first case. If you declare a variable of Type Base and assign an instance of type Derived it won't call the derived method fooB but the one from the base class? Or would it even throw some error?

Comment: @thuri:  There are no `virtual` methods here, so there is no polymorphism in the first place.  But if there were, you could do `Base* p = new Derived;` and then call those virtuals, getting the polymorphic behavior you desire.  I suspect you're remembering how polymorphism works incorrectly.

Comment: @John :-) I spent quite some time now in Java and C#. Of course you're right that virtual must be used in C++ (and C#) to get real polymorphism. But what i'm curios about is what would happen, if you specify fooB as virtual and make fooB private in a derived class? Would this bring up a compiler error? And if not what would be the runtime behaviour in that case?

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly the kind of answer I would look for.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, then what you are looking is Inheritance.  Which means if A inherits B, it inherits B's methods and properties, if and only they are cleared protected or public.

Check these links:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gq2Igdc-OSI

Answer (score 0):

You can make fooB private and it will be invisible in the derived class.
Learn about private/protected/public modifiers and about public/private/protected inheritance. These are tools you need.

Comment: Making fooB private works but also make it cannot be called by instance of class `Base`. But in my program, I don't want to do any damage things on class `Base`. Is there other ways to do that?